# Bilinear transformation of continuous time state space system

Tags: state-space, bilinear-transform

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the bilinear transform for a set of continuous time state-space matrices. I've found plenty of websites which list steps to perform the conversion (here [1](http://au.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bilinear.html) or here [2](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-245-multivariable-control-systems-spring-2004/lecture-notes/lec11_6245_2004.pdf) or here [3](https://math.aalto.fi/~jmalinen/MyPSFilesInWeb/milano-talk.pdf)) - but haven't found any derivation or insight into how they came about. When I attempt to do it myself, I keep getting terms in z which I can't seem to get rid of.

To make the problem clear, if I define the bilinear transform as:

$$ s=\frac{\alpha\left(z-1\right)}{z+1} $$

Where alpha is usually given as 2/T.

The transfer function of a continuous-time state-space system can be given as:

$$ H(s) = \mathbf{C}(s\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{D} $$

How do I derive the expressions for the matrices of the discrete time version bilinear transformed model:

$$ H(z) = \mathbf{C_d}(z\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A_d})^{-1}\mathbf{B_d} + \mathbf{D_d} $$

When I make the variable change, I keep getting extra terms in z which I don't know what to do with. I'm kinda hoping this is just me failing to have a strong grasp of matrix operations. Any insight (including if I am going about this completely the wrong way) would be really appreciated!

--- Edit with answer.

Thanks to Klaz for posting an answer to this first. I managed to work through the problem today and thought I would post my own alternate working here.

Given the typical state-space equations:

$$ s\mathbf{Q}(s) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q}(s) + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}(s) $$
$$ \mathbf{Y}(s) = \mathbf{C}\mathbf{Q}(s) + \mathbf{D}\mathbf{X}(s) $$

Focus on the state update equation first and make the bilinear substitution:

$$ \frac{\alpha\left(z-1\right)}{z+1} \mathbf{Q}(z) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{Q}(z) + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}(z) $$

We manipulate this expression to make the LHS $z\mathbf{Q}(z)$:

$$ \alpha\left(z-1\right) \mathbf{Q}(z) = \mathbf{A}\left(z+1\right)\mathbf{Q}(z) + \mathbf{B}\left(z+1\right)\mathbf{X}(z) $$

$$ z\left(\alpha\mathbf{I}-A\right)\mathbf{Q}(z) = \left(\alpha\mathbf{I}+A\right)\mathbf{Q}(z) + \mathbf{B}\left(z+1\right)\mathbf{X}(z) $$

$$ z\mathbf{Q}(z) = \left(\alpha\mathbf{I}-A\right)^{-1}\left(\alpha\mathbf{I}+A\right)\mathbf{Q}(z) + \left(\alpha\mathbf{I}-A\right)^{-1}\mathbf{B}\left(z+1\right)\mathbf{X}(z) $$

This instantly gives us $\mathbf{A_d}$ as:

$$ \mathbf{A_d} = \left(\alpha\mathbf{I}-A\right)^{-1}\left(\alpha\mathbf{I}+A\right) $$

We know that the linear $(z+1)$ term of $\mathbf{X}(z)$ can be applied wherever $\mathbf{Q}(z)$ is used. We apply this in the output expression to give the new output discrete equation as:

$$ z\mathbf{Q}(z) = \left(\alpha\mathbf{I}-A\right)^{-1}\left(\alpha\mathbf{I}+A\right)\mathbf{Q}(z) + \left(\alpha\mathbf{I}-A\right)^{-1}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{X}(z) $$
$$ \mathbf{Y}(z) = \mathbf{C}\left(z+1\right)\mathbf{Q}(z) + \mathbf{D}\mathbf{X}(z)$$
$$ \mathbf{Y}(z) = \mathbf{C}z\mathbf{Q}(z) + \mathbf{C}\mathbf{Q}(z) + \mathbf{D}\mathbf{X}(z)$$

We can now pull out $\mathbf{B_d}$ as:

$$ \mathbf{B_d} = \left(\alpha\mathbf{I}-A\right)^{-1}\mathbf{B} $$

Because we know an expression for $z\mathbf{Q}(z)$, we can formulate $\mathbf{Y}(z)$ as:

$$ \mathbf{Y}(z) = \mathbf{C}\left(\mathbf{A_d}\mathbf{Q}(z) + \mathbf{B_d} \mathbf{X}(z) \right) + \mathbf{C}\mathbf{Q}(z) + \mathbf{D}\mathbf{X}(z)$$

$$ \mathbf{Y}(z) = \mathbf{C}\left(\mathbf{A_d}+\mathbf{I}\right)\mathbf{Q}(z) + \left(\mathbf{C}\mathbf{B_d} + \mathbf{D}\right)\mathbf{X}(z) $$

Giving:

$$ \mathbf{C_d} = \mathbf{C}\left(\mathbf{A_d}+\mathbf{I}\right) $$
$$ \mathbf{D_d} = \mathbf{C}\mathbf{B_d} + \mathbf{D} $$

Comment: I noticed that your solution is slight different from the result in [1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bilinear.html "this text appears when you mouse over"), I also find different solution [here](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~maapc/static/files/CACSD/Slides/chapter2.pdf "this text appears when you mouse over"). Obviously, moving the linear term $(z+1)$ from $B$ matrix to $C$ matrix would not change the total transfer function. But would inner state matrix $Q(z)$ lose its structure? It is no longer discretization of original $Q(s)$ but something else?

Comment: I don't understand the part:
We know that the linear $(z+1)$ term of $\mathbf{X}(z)$ can be applied wherever $\mathbf{Q}(z)$ is used.
Why?

Comment: First, if you're doing control systems then your knowledge of the parameters is inexact, so you may as well use something that makes the math easy.  The [forward Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) works.  I.e. $x_n = (\mathbf I + T_s \mathbf A)x_{n-1} + T_s \mathbf B$.  Second, if you feel that exactitude is important, and since it's 2021 and we're surrounded by a sea of computers, use [the exact method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization#Discretization_of_linear_state_space_models).  Note that it's easy to get over the problem with $\mathbf A$ being singular.

Comment: @JuanGonzalezBurgos yes, this was very poor wording on my part. If ()=() and $\mathbf{A}(z)=(z+1)\mathbf{X}(z)$, because the expressions are linear, we can move the (+1) from the second expression into the first e.g. ()=(+1)() and $\mathbf{A}(z)=\mathbf{X}(z)$. This is equivalent to a change of variable - but I was lazy and didn't change the variable.

Comment: @TimWescott thanks for the additional comments. The particular use-case surrounding my question didn't arise from control systems, but from attempting to build algorithms that would efficiently realise parallel-form (as opposed to cascade) discrete implementations of high-order filters.

State-space representation is IMO widely under-appreciated for it's uses outside of control systems. Even regular digital IIR filters can have their performance dramatically improved by designing the filter in state space.

Comment: @NicholasAppleton: 15 or 20 years ago I was implementing IIR filters in a DSP chip as state space, using matrix multiplies -- the overhead of _just_ doing the computation you wanted programmatically, vs. doing a bunch of MAC operations with zero as a coefficient was more expensive until you got up to 4th- or 6th- or 8th-order filters or some such.  This was with a TMS32F2812 -- your mileage may vary (and I can't remember exactly where the break-even point happened).

Comment: 15 years ago I would not been able to speak intelligently on this topic and 20 years ago I would have had no idea what any of this is. :)  
I was building 16th order elliptic filters and trying to implement them entirely using vector instructions on x86. I was block-diagonalising the 16x16 state transition matrix (i.e. parallelising the filters) to avoid any zero multiplies. I put a blog together a little while documenting some of this if you're interested: https://www.appletonaudio.com/blog/2020/state-space-representation-an-engineering-primer/ please comment on that if you have insights!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same question last week, but I've managed to find how to derive it (getting rid of those $z$ terms is indeed tricky). I will give here detailed demonstration of how to arrive to the result given in [1](http://au.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bilinear.html) (with, in your notation, $\alpha = 2 \lambda$).

So we define our new discrete-time function transfer as

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
H_d(z) &=& H(\frac{\alpha\left(z-1\right)}{z+1}) \\
&=& \mathbf{C} \left[ \frac{\alpha\left(z-1\right)}{z+1}\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A} \right]^{-1}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{D} \\
&=& \frac{z+1}{\alpha} \mathbf{C} \left[ \left(z-1\right)\mathbf{I}- \frac{z+1}{\alpha}\mathbf{A} \right]^{-1}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{D} \\
&=& \frac{z+1}{\alpha} \mathbf{C} \left[ z \left(\mathbf{I} - \frac{1}{\alpha} \mathbf{A} \right) - \left(\mathbf{I} + \frac{1}{\alpha} \mathbf{A}\right) \right]^{-1}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{D} \\
\end{array}
$$

For sake of notation, let $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{I} - \frac{1}{\alpha} \mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{I} + \frac{1}{\alpha} \mathbf{A}$ (important remark useful later on: $\mathbf{P} + \mathbf{Q} = 2 \mathbf{I}$). Then

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
H_d(z) &=& \frac{z+1}{\alpha} \mathbf{C} \left[ z \mathbf{P} - \mathbf{Q} \right]^{-1}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{D} \\
&=& \frac{z+1}{\alpha} \mathbf{C} \left[ z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{P}^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \right]^{-1} \mathbf{P}^{-1} \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{D} \\
&=& \frac{z+1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \left[ z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{P}^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \right]^{-1} \left( \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha}}  \mathbf{P}^{-1} \mathbf{B} \right) + \mathbf{D} \\
&=& \frac{z+1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \left[ z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A_d} \right]^{-1} \mathbf{B_d} + \mathbf{D}
\end{array}
$$

where we defined

$ \mathbf{A_d} = \mathbf{P}^{-1} \mathbf{Q} $
and
$ \mathbf{B_d} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha}}  \mathbf{P}^{-1} \mathbf{B} $.
Furthermore, we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{z+1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C}
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \left( z + 1 \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \left( z \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A_d} - \mathbf{A_d} \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \left[ \left( z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A_d} \right) + \left( \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A_d} \right) \right] \\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \left[ \left( z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A_d} \right) + \mathbf{P}^{-1} \left( \mathbf{P} + \mathbf{Q} \right) \right] \\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \left[ \left( z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A_d} \right) + 2 \mathbf{P}^{-1} \right]
\end{array}
$$

which gives us

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
H_d(z)
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \left[ \left( z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A_d} \right) + 2 \mathbf{P}^{-1} \right] \left[ z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A_d} \right]^{-1} \mathbf{B_d} + \mathbf{D} \\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \mathbf{B_d} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha}} \mathbf{C} \mathbf{P}^{-1} \left[ z \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A_d} \right]^{-1} \mathbf{B_d} + \mathbf{D} \\
&=& \mathbf{C_d}(z\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A_d})^{-1}\mathbf{B_d} + \mathbf{D_d} 
\end{array}
$$
with
$ \mathbf{C_d} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha}} \mathbf{C} \mathbf{P}^{-1} $
and
$ \mathbf{D_d} = \mathbf{D} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \alpha}} \mathbf{C} \mathbf{B_d} $.
Replacing $\mathbf{P}$ and $\alpha = 2 \lambda$ gives the results in [1](http://au.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bilinear.html).

PS: the same idea can be used to prove the discrete-time state-space representation found using  Generalized Bilinear Transform ($s \leftarrow \alpha \frac{z - 1}{\beta z + \left(1-\beta\right)}$) or First-order Holder methods.

Comment: Thanks Klaz for taking the time to post a solution! I managed to work through this one today after almost giving up. I think I went about it in a slightly different way and have added my own working to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add to this some specifics on the MATLAB implementation.

Continuous time system:
$$\dot{x} = A x + B u$$

Laplace transform:
$$sx = Ax + Bu$$

Tustin discretization:
$$\frac{\alpha(z-1)}{z+1}x = Ax + Bu$$
where $\alpha = 2f_\text{s}$, $f_\text{s}$ being the sampling frequency.

When $z \ne -1$, multiplying through by $(z+1)$, and rearranging,
$$ z\left[x - \frac{1}{\alpha}(Ax+Bu)\right] = x + \frac{1}{\alpha}(Ax + Bu)$$

Motivated by this, do the following coordinate transformation (this is what is done in MATLAB, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/continuous-discrete-conversion-methods.html#bs78nig-8)):
$$
\begin{aligned}
    x_\text{d} &= x - \frac{1}{\alpha}(Ax+Bu) \\
               &= \left(I - \frac{1}{\alpha}A\right)x - \frac{1}{\alpha}Bu 
\end{aligned}
$$

Then the inverse coordinate transformation,
$$x = \left(I - \frac{1}{\alpha}A\right)^{-1}
      \left(x_\text{d}+\frac{1}{\alpha}Bu\right)$$

Substituting back,
$$z x_\text{d} = \left(I + \frac{1}{\alpha}A\right)
                 \left(I - \frac{1}{\alpha}A\right)^{-1}x_\text{d}
               + \left[\left(I + \frac{1}{\alpha}A\right)
                       \left(I - \frac{1}{\alpha}A\right)^{-1} + I\right]
                 \frac{1}{\alpha}Bu $$

Define
$$
\begin{aligned}
    A_\text{d} &= \left(I + \frac{1}{\alpha}A\right)
                 \left(I - \frac{1}{\alpha}A\right)^{-1} \\
    B_\text{d} &= \frac{1}{\alpha}(A_\text{d} + I)B
\end{aligned}
$$

Then,
$$x_\text{d}^{k+1} = A_\text{d}x_\text{d}^k + B_\text{d}u^k$$

To check if this is indeed what $\texttt{c2d}$ in MATLAB is doing, try the following:

```
% Construct a second order system to test
f = 5; % frequency
zet = 0.05; % damping ratio
w = 2*pi*f; % circular frequency

% state space representation
A = [0 1; -w^2 -2*zet*w]; 
B = [0; 1];
C = [1 0];
D = [];
sys = ss(A, B, C, D);

% Discrete time system using Tustin
Ts = 0.01; % sampling time (100Hz)
sysd = c2d(sys, 0.01, 'Tustin');

% Construct discrete time matrices using the formulas derived
alph = 2/Ts;
Ad = (eye(2)+A/alph)/(eye(2)-A/alph);
Bd = (1/alph)*(Ad + eye(2))*B;

% Compare
fprintf('Compare Ad:\n')
disp([Ad sysd.A])
fprintf('Compare Bd:\n')
disp([Bd sysd.B])
```

This gives
$$A_\text{d} = \begin{bmatrix}0.9526 & 0.0096 \\-9.4865 & 0.9224 \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$B_\text{d} = \begin{bmatrix}0.0000 \\ 0.0096 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: This is a good answer, but I had already upvoted it.  It's actually a really good answer.