# What exactly are the assumptions behind Tustin's formula? Application on state space models

Tags: z-transform, laplace-transform, state-space, bilinear-transform

I was parsing the forum when I saw [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45042/bilinear-transformation-of-continuous-time-state-space-system) post surging out of the depths of this forum like an old Kraken. The problem is quite simple.

You have a  continuous time state space model :

$$
\begin{split}
\dot{X} &= AX+BU\\
Y &= CX
\end{split}
\tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
The state equation giving in Laplace :

$$(sI-A)X(s) = BU(s) \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Then compute the equivalent discrete time model by using the Bilinear transformation :

$$s = \alpha \frac{z-1}{z+1}\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Let us focus on the state transition matrix. After some tedious calculations they get :

$$A_d = (\alpha I-A)^{-1}(\alpha I+A)\tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

The thing is that I know another way to solve this. You just solve the linear differential equation given by \ref{eq4}. An exact solution is, between instants $kT$ and $(k+1)T$ :

$$
X((k+1)T) = e^{AT}X(kT) + e^{AT}\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T} e^{-A\tau}BU(\tau)d\tau \tag{5}\label{eq5}
$$

clearly we see that, no matter what assumption we make to compute $\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T} e^{-A\tau}BU(\tau)d\tau$, even if we use the the trapezoidal rule, we will have
$$A_d = e^{AT}\tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

here comes my question. I always heard that Tustin's rule was equivalent to using the trapezoidal rule to integrate the differential equation. Since clearly we have :

$$ (\alpha I-A)^{-1}(\alpha I+A) \neq e^{AT}$$

it must be more complicated than that. Is it because I didn't discretize the differential equation \ref{eq5}? Is there a bilinear transform that is equivalent to solving \ref{eq5}? What do we exactly assume when we use Tustin's bilinear transformation?

Comment: There's [another answer that deals specifically with the trapezoidal integration and Tustin's method](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19225/audio-eq-cookbook-without-frequency-warping/19248#19248).  I thought I did this before but it's so hard to find old stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do we exactly assume when we use Tustin's bilinear transformation?

I'm not sure what you mean by "trapezoidal rule", but Tustin's approximation is the $z$-domain way to use a discrete time trapezoidal approximation for integration -- i.e., that
$$\int x(t) dt \simeq \frac T 2 \sum x(nT) + x\left((n-1)T\right)$$

If you derive the $z$ transform by starting with the declaration that $z = e^{sT}$, then for $sT \ll 1$,

$$\begin{align}
z &= e^{sT} \\
\\
  &= \frac{e^{sT/2}}{e^{-sT/2}} \\
\\
  &\approx \frac{1+\frac{sT}{2}}{1-\frac{sT}{2}} \\
\end{align} $$

Solve for $s$.

$$\frac T 2 \frac{z + 1}{z - 1} \simeq s^{-1}$$
(try this out with the first term of the Taylor's expansion of $z = e^{sT}$)

**That** is what we assume when we use the Tustin's approximation.

> Is there a bilinear transform that is equivalent to solving (4)?

Nope.  It's called Tustin's *approximation* for a reason.

For the general case where $U(t)$ varies arbitrarily between sampling instants, there really isn't an exact conversion from the continuous-time to the discrete-time (although they'll all have $A_d = e^{AT}$).

When $U(t)$ is some known then you can find it -- in fact I used to use this when doing state space control.  But if you don't have control of $U(t)$ between sampling intervals, then you just need to accept that you're going to approximate things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had a mismatch between my equation references and my labels. my 4s were supposed to be 5s but you didn't let that distract you. I think I have a better grasp of what was troubling me. I'll take some time to put it down on paper and I'll come back then. EDIT : I also found [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/62752/justification-of-bilinear-transform) post about bilinear transform

Comment: If you decide that this is _the_ answer to your question, check it as such -- it'll help others when they're asking the same thing and find your question.

Comment: In the end my problem was that Tustin's formula is equivalent to the trapezoidal approximation in the context of solving $\dot{X}=f(X,t)$ we integrate $X(t)=X(0)+\int f(X,t)dt$ and approximate the integrale with the trapezoidal rule. In the case of my equation \ref{eq5} what was done was, with $f(X,t) = AX+BU$ exact integration for the $AX$ term and an approximation for $BU$. But if you want Tustin's formula to be equivalent to trapezoidal integration you need to integrate the whole f with trapezoidal approximation.